# Cast from pointer to integer of different size warning

Tags: c

I am getting

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size

at line `return (Node *) ((unsigned int)(a) ^ (unsigned int)(b));`. How can I get rid of it ?
The intent of XORing the addresses is to implement a XORed link list which is a doubly link list and it consists of only one field to traverse back and forth in the list. The npx field contained the difference between the pointer to the next node and the pointer to the previous node. The pointer difference is calculated by XORing.

```
  typedef struct  _node {
    int data;
    struct _node *npx;
}Node;

Node * XOR(Node *a, Node *b){
    return (Node *) ((unsigned int)(a) ^ (unsigned int)(b));
}

void addNode(int num, Node **head, int position, int flag)
{
    Node * temp, *q;
    Node *node  = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node ->data = num;
    node->npx = XOR(*head, NULL);
    Node *next = XOR((*head)->npx, NULL);
    (*head)->npx = XOR(node, next);
    *head = node;
    }

int main()
{
    Node *head  = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->data =23;
    head->npx= NULL;

    addNode(32, &head, 1, 0);
    addNode(33, &head, 1, 0);
    addNode(34, &head, 1, 0);
    addNode(35, &head, 1, 0);
    addNode(36, &head, 1, 0);
    addNode(37, &head, 1, 0);
    addNode(178, &head, 3, 1);
    displayNode(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you XORing pointers?

Comment: You can get rid of the warning by not casting pointers to integers.

Comment: Actually, you can do interesting things by XORing (relative) pointers, like squeezing the forward and backward pointer of a doubly linked list into the same field. But that is rather an assembler than a C domain and maybe long out of date nowadays.

Comment: @dbush The reason for XORing pointer addresses, as tofro mentioned, I am trying to implement a memory efficient doubly linked list by squeezing the forward and backward pointer in the same field. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list

Comment: int is not necessarily the same size as pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#include <inttypes.h>` and an integer type `uintptr_t`, which is defined to be able to be converted from any valid pointer to `void` in [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.18.1.4 to avoid the warning.

```
Node * XOR(Node *a, Node *b){
    return (Node *) ((uintptr_t)(a) ^ (uintptr_t)(b));
}
```

Comment: `uintptr_t` is also defined in `<stdint.h>`, which doesn't bring in all the printf and scanf format string definitions.

Comment: note: this causes undefined behaviour if the result of conversion to `Node *` is not a valid pointer (or null)